# Issue with Rewrite rule

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

on firing URL,

```
http://www.MYSITE.org/reg/u/32
```

i want to forward it to this link,

```
http://www.MYSITE.org/register/sponsorship/?u=32
```

i have tried

```
RewriteRule /reg/u/([0-9]+)/$ register/sponsorship/?u=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule /reg/u/([0-9]+)$ register/sponsorship/?u=$1 [QSA]
```

but not working. what is missing? any help?

Comment: where will `http://www.MYSITE.org/reg/u/32` forward to ?

Comment: that should be forwarded to http://www.MYSITE.org/register/sponsorship/?u=32

Comment: but how does it behave now?

Comment: what you mean by how it behaves?

Comment: As I asked in 1st comment, where will `http://www.MYSITE.org/reg/u/32` forward to NOW ?

Comment: in no man's land :P , i mean there is no page for that link, that's why i wanted to forward it to mentioned one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.org/register/sponsorship/?u=$1 [L]
```